# Circle radius problem

Tags: geometry

Right isosceles triangle **ABC** inscribed in circle **k(O,R)**. Circle **k1(O1,R1)** is tangential to **AB**, **AC** and circle **k**. Find **R1** in terms of  **R**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join $CO$ and let $Q$ be the intersection with $AO_1$. As $AO_1$ is the bisector of $\angle BAC$ you can find $OQ=R/(1+\sqrt2)$. Then by Pythagoras theorem you can compute $OM=\sqrt{R^2+2RR_1}$ so that $AM=R+\sqrt{R^2+2RR_1}$. You can now exploit the similitude between $AOQ$ and $AMO_1$ to get $AO:AM=OQ:MO_1$, so that finally $R_1=2R(2-\sqrt2)$.

Comment: So $R_1<R$? Can that be right?

Comment: @DavidQuinn You are right: I made a mistake in the final calculation, which I have now corrected.